# Self hosting GraphHopper Directions API

Tags: openstreetmap, graphhopper

We are looking for an offline routing and reverse geocoding service.

GraphHopper advertises that its [Directions API can be self-hosted](https://graphhopper.com/#enterprise):

> **GraphHopper Directions API Self-Hosting / On-Premises**
>
> The Directions API comes as a cloud service where you pay on-demand. The API is also
>   available as on-premises solution (self-hosted), which gives you
>   maximum performance, customization possibilities, independence; all in
>   your hands!

After installing GraphHopper on my local instance as per [these instructions](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.5/docs/web/quickstart.md), I am able to perform routing queries successfully through the localhost HTTP API.

**How do I get reverse geocoding working?** I cannot find any documentation on this and the code on GitHub doesn't seem to hint towards anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GraphHopper Directions API is a different product than the open source GraphHopper routing engine. The GraphHopper Directions API currently consists of

- the Routing API (based on the GraphHopper routing engine),
- the Matrix API,
- the Geocoding API and
- the Route Optimization API.

Currently they are no longer available for self-hosting. Note: I'm one of the authors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will contact GraphHopper via mail :)

Comment: @Karussell what is the difference between between the API (https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/routing/) (with payment) and the Graphhopper core (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphhopper/graphhopper-core/0.9.0) (free) i want to get the distance between 2 points also the best path between 2 points

Comment: Mostly none, the enterprise edition has truck profiles, route optimization and improved ETAs and TomTom data alternative. And then there are several other APIs https://www.graphhopper.com/open-source/

Comment: @Karussell Can I use GraphHopper as a bing map replacement ? Can I display map & route and navigate through route ? I'm building application in Angular and want to use open source for real time car movement. Please guide m.e Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>GraphHopper is a routing service, not a geocoder.</strike>

According to [this issue](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api/issues/2) the Geocoder is separate from GraphHopper and only available in the Directions API for business.

If you are looking for a free OSM-based geocoding service then take a look at [search engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) in the OSM wiki.

Comment: According to [GitHub page](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api/blob/master/README.md), the "Directions API" consists of a Geocoding API.  Is this not available with the open source version?

Comment: Oh you are right, I've missed that. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the geocoding comes with the current version. Only the route api seems to be available.