# Adding additional vehicles to local instance of graphhopper

Tags: graphhopper

Really new to graphhopper and an inexperienced java programmer so I need a little help extending graphhopper core. What I've done so far is install the graphhopper core from the link on the quickstart guide found [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.5/docs/web/quickstart.md). I'm then able to follow the rest of the instructions and get a local instance up and running just fine and interact with it using R and the API instructions. I would like to add support for bike, foot, and transit routing. As per the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897870/graphhopper-vehicle-car-works-but-foot-or-bike-dont-work/33912125#33912125), I first attempted to modify `graph.flagEncoders=car` to `graph.flagEncoders=car,foot, bike` in the "config-example.properties" file. And that's where things fail. When attempting to run the program in the command prompt, it then fails at this point. Any help and direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: 8/24/2018**

Below is a screenshot of the command prompt when using `graph.flagEncoders=car,foot, bike` in the "config-example.properties" file. Note that I'm using the example osm data found on the quickstart guide.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to remove the created caching-folder before retry? Or what exactly is your error? Also combining those with transit is currently not possible (but car,foot,bike should be): https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/1023

Comment: My apologies if this is obvious, but where would the cache folder be created? See the edit to the question.

Comment: If you have a `file.pbf` the cache folder is `file-gh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Karussell's comment, in this instance all you have to do is delete the *.osm-gh cache folder that's created by Graphhopper.